# Adjusting page layout

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am creating a simple registration page and I'm using Bootstrap-5 for the layout. I need the second row (the one starting with %MP1) to have all the elements of the page including that last field that is being placed on the third row (image attached). Is there a way to have it all fit on this same row?

[image: Snapshot of the page]

Follows the code:

```html
<!-- Bootstrap-5 -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- Body -->
<div class="container ms-1 me-1">
  <div class="jumbotron bg-danger">
  </div>

  <h2>Cadastro de Produtos</h2>
  <form method="post">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-1 mt-3 align-self-center d-flex justify-content-start">
        <label for="tipo" class="form-label">Tipo:</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 mt-3">
        <select class="form-select" aria-label="tipo" name="tipo" id="tipo">
          <option value="">Selecione o tipo</option>
          <option value="1">Bobina</option>
          <option value="2">Saco</option>
          <option value="3">Folha Cortada</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1 mt-3 align-self-center d-flex justify-content-start">
        <label for="config" class="form-label">Configuração:</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 mt-3">
        <select class="form-select" aria-label="config" name="config" id="config">
          <option value="">Selecione a Configuração</option>
          <option value="1"></option>
          <option value="2">Tubular</option>
          <option value="3">Folha Simples</option>
          <option value="4">Folha Dupla</option>
          <option value="5">Ref. 1 Lado</option>
          <option value="6">Bolha</option>
          <option value="7">Gofrada</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="mt-3 col-md-auto align-self-center d-flex justify-content-start">
        <label for="MP" class="form-label">Matéria Prima:</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 mt-3 align-self-center d-flex justify-content-start">
        <select class="form-select" aria-label="MP" name="MP" id="MP">
          <option value="">Selecione a MP</option>
          <option value="1">Reciclado Canela</option>
          <option value="2">Reciclado Preto</option>
          <option value="3">Reciclado Colorido</option>
          <option value="4">Reciclado Cristal</option>
          <option value="5">PEBD Virgem</option>
          <option value="6">PEAD Virgem</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1 mt-3 form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="check-blenda" onchange="validarForm()">
        <label class="form-check-label d-flex justify-content-center" for="check-blenda">Blenda</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="mt-3 col-md-1 align-self-center">
        <label for="perc-mp1" class="form-label">% MP 1:</label>
      </div>
      <div class="mt-3 col-md-1">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="perc-mp1" name="perc-mp1" id="perc-mp1" disabled>
      </div>
      <div class="mt-3 col-md-auto align-self-center d-flex justify-content-start">
        <label for="MP2" class="form-label">Matéria Prima 2:</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 mt-3 align-self-center d-flex justify-content-start">
        <select class="form-select" aria-label="MP2" name="MP2" id="MP2" disabled>
          <option value="">Selecione a MP</option>
          <option value="1">Reciclado Canela</option>
          <option value="2">Reciclado Preto</option>
          <option value="3">Reciclado Colorido</option>
          <option value="4">Reciclado Cristal</option>
          <option value="5">PEBD Virgem</option>
          <option value="6">PEAD Virgem</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="mt-3 col-md-1 align-self-center d-flex justify-content-end">
        <label for="perc-mp2" class="form-label">% MP 2:</label>
      </div>
      <div class="mt-3 col-md-1">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="perc-mp2" name="perc-mp2" id="perc-mp2" disabled>
      </div>
      <div class="mt-3 col-md-auto align-self-center d-flex justify-content-start">
        <label for="MP3" class="form-label">Matéria Prima 3:</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 mt-3 align-self-center d-flex justify-content-start">
        <select class="form-select" aria-label="MP3" name="MP3" id="MP3" disabled>
          <option value="">Selecione a MP</option>
          <option value="1">Reciclado Canela</option>
          <option value="2">Reciclado Preto</option>
          <option value="3">Reciclado Colorido</option>
          <option value="4">Reciclado Cristal</option>
          <option value="5">PEBD Virgem</option>
          <option value="6">PEAD Virgem</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="mt-3 col-md-1 align-self-center d-flex justify-content-end">
        <label for="perc-mp3" class="form-label">% MP 3:</label>
      </div>
      <div class="mt-3 col-md-1">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="perc-mp3" name="perc-mp3" id="perc-mp3" disabled>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mt-4 col-md-auto align-self-center d-flex justify-content-start">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="validarblendas()">Cadastrar</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: You have to keep the sum of the column numbers per row at 12, that is the basis of how the BS grid works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your use case is not a good fit for the BS grid.
The desired behavior can still be achieved, instead of `.row` use a flex container with [wrapping](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/flex/#wrap) toggled at the medium breakpoint: `.d-flex.flex-wrap.flex-md-nowrap`.
In the snippet below, I removed all the unneeded `.col-*` wrappers, then I added `.flex-shrink-0` to all of the `.form-label`s to keep them from wrapping, `.align-items-baseline` to the flex container to align label text with input text, and `.me-1` to everything in the row allowing a minimal amount of spacing.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container ms-1 me-1">
  <div class="jumbotron bg-danger">
  </div>

  <h2>Cadastro de Produtos</h2>
  <form method="post">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-1 mt-3 align-self-center d-flex justify-content-start">
        <label for="tipo" class="form-label">Tipo:</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 mt-3">
        <select class="form-select" aria-label="tipo" name="tipo" id="tipo">
          <option value="">Selecione o tipo</option>
          <option value="1">Bobina</option>
          <option value="2">Saco</option>
          <option value="3">Folha Cortada</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1 mt-3 align-self-center d-flex justify-content-start">
        <label for="config" class="form-label">Configuração:</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 mt-3">
        <select class="form-select" aria-label="config" name="config" id="config">
          <option value="">Selecione a Configuração</option>
          <option value="1"></option>
          <option value="2">Tubular</option>
          <option value="3">Folha Simples</option>
          <option value="4">Folha Dupla</option>
          <option value="5">Ref. 1 Lado</option>
          <option value="6">Bolha</option>
          <option value="7">Gofrada</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="mt-3 col-md-auto align-self-center d-flex justify-content-start">
        <label for="MP" class="form-label">Matéria Prima:</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 mt-3 align-self-center d-flex justify-content-start">
        <select class="form-select" aria-label="MP" name="MP" id="MP">
          <option value="">Selecione a MP</option>
          <option value="1">Reciclado Canela</option>
          <option value="2">Reciclado Preto</option>
          <option value="3">Reciclado Colorido</option>
          <option value="4">Reciclado Cristal</option>
          <option value="5">PEBD Virgem</option>
          <option value="6">PEAD Virgem</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1 mt-3 form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="check-blenda" onchange="validarForm()">
        <label class="form-check-label d-flex justify-content-center" for="check-blenda">Blenda</label>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="d-flex flex-wrap flex-md-nowrap align-items-baseline">
      <label for="perc-mp1" class="form-label flex-shrink-0 mt-3 me-1">% MP 1:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control mt-3 me-1" aria-label="perc-mp1" name="perc-mp1" id="perc-mp1" disabled>
      <br />
      <label for="MP2" class="form-label flex-shrink-0 mt-3 me-1">Matéria Prima 2:</label>
      <select class="form-select mt-3 me-1" aria-label="MP2" name="MP2" id="MP2" disabled>
        <option value="">Selecione a MP</option>
        <option value="1">Reciclado Canela</option>
        <option value="2">Reciclado Preto</option>
        <option value="3">Reciclado Colorido</option>
        <option value="4">Reciclado Cristal</option>
        <option value="5">PEBD Virgem</option>
        <option value="6">PEAD Virgem</option>
      </select>
      <label for="perc-mp2" class="form-label flex-shrink-0 mt-3 me-1">% MP 2:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control mt-3 me-1" aria-label="perc-mp2" name="perc-mp2" id="perc-mp2" disabled>
      <label for="MP3" class="form-label flex-shrink-0 mt-3 me-1">Matéria Prima 3:</label>
      <select class="form-select mt-3 me-1" aria-label="MP3" name="MP3" id="MP3" disabled>
        <option value="">Selecione a MP</option>
        <option value="1">Reciclado Canela</option>
        <option value="2">Reciclado Preto</option>
        <option value="3">Reciclado Colorido</option>
        <option value="4">Reciclado Cristal</option>
        <option value="5">PEBD Virgem</option>
        <option value="6">PEAD Virgem</option>
      </select>
      <label for="perc-mp3" class="form-label flex-shrink-0 mt-3 me-1">% MP 3:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control mt-3 me-1" aria-label="perc-mp3" name="perc-mp3" id="perc-mp3" disabled>

    </div>
    <div class="mt-4">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mt-3 me-1" onclick="validarblendas()">Cadastrar</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```